# Question regarding dimension of subspace generated by set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a set of vectors $V=\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ where only three of them are linearly independent and I use them to create a basis for the subspace generated by V such that
$B=\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

Am I correct to say that the dimension of the subspace generated by B is 4 (it generates vectors with 4 variables), but that the span of B doesn't encompass all of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

edit: I guess what's confusing me about the exercise is that I can't figure out how to calculate the change of basis matrix from standard basis to $B=\{(1, 2, 0, 1), (0, 8, 0, 7), (0, 0, 1, 0)\}$.

Comment: How could three vectors generate a $4$ dimensional space?

Comment: Note:  from what you said, we can't determine the dimension of the span of $B$. We don't know if those three vectors are linearly independent or not.

Comment: It’s not relevant that the variables are 4, what’s important instead is that none of those are redundant.

Comment: After reading the first comment I think I get it now: two linearly independent R3 vectors would form a plane in space, so three linearly independent R4 vectors would form an R3 element in an R4 space?